wxGraphicsContext and wxDC
I have written a chart application all using wxDC and its subclasses. However, I realized wxGraphicsContext offers truly superior advantages to wxDC but has its own ecosystem and this is very much inconsistent with wxWidget's ecosystem (such as wxRect to wxRect2DDouble and so on and even for basic member function names are different GetTopLeft vs GetLeftTop).
I wonder keeping wxGraphicsContext like an outsider is intentional? Will it be deprecated? If not why is the integration to wxWidgets so poor?

with wxDC you are working with screen coordinates, but with wxGraphicsContext you are working with virtual coordinates .... think about google maps where you have an infinite draggable screen, that's the idea, in such cases you want to have different coordinates objects to not accidentally pass one where the other is expected, also wxGraphicsContext might use GPU

@AhmedAEK, not necessarily, you can work with screen or logical coordinates with wxDC. I am not a QT guy but as I understand QT's QPainter can work with different backends and seamlessly integrated with QT ecosystem.

for Qt the equivalent would be QGraphicsScene, both of them support anti-aliased drawing, Rotation, layers, etc... though Qt seems to use the same primitives as normal QPainter,  do note that those objects use float for painting, whereas wxDC uses integers for coordinates, you need float coordinates since each pixel in your transformed space could be mapped to multiple pixels on the real screen, so half pixels still make sense.

wxGraphicsContext is not an outsider, it's indeed the recommended way to do graphics since more than 10 years, and you should use it.
The discrepancies between wxRect and wxRect2DDouble are unfortunate, but really not a huge deal in practice.

There are many discrepancies unfortunately. There are member funcs wxRect has but not wxRect2DDouble or other way around. I wonder why they were not template'd in the first place for consistency. Furthermore, wxPoint uses p.x whereas wxPoint2DDouble p.m_x. When the code base is fairly large, this is truly a lot of work(I mean a lot). But thanks anyways.

I have finally managed to switch to wxGraphicsContext but it works much slower than wxDC based drawing. I turned off antialiasing which sped up things but then font rendering was really unpleasant.

As you're probably using Windows, you could try using D2D renderer instead of the default GDI+ one, it can provide better performance.

I tried that too. On Windows 11 it was OK but on Windows 10 it did not work at all (charts were not drawn).

D2D definitely should work on Windows 10, please open an issue if it doesn't (but please check the drawing sample first to make sure it's really a problem in wxWidgets).

Btw, is there a reason version 3.2.6 not on vcpkg yet?

@macroland, its been released only about a week ago. Give it a time. In the meantime - build it yourself...
